# Can Nagios hit any Custom API?

Tags: java, nagios

I am working on Nagios core. I have configured Nagios core to send email notification when service is in warning and critical state. I have one custom API in JAVA which sends emails.
I want that Nagios email alerts should go through this custom API. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by creating new command definition, one for service and next one for host notification. It is very similar what you already have for email notifications.

Recommended way is create new script in your favorite language (Bash, Python, Perl,..) which will contain required stuff for call your API. This script should be included into your command definition as I write above.

You can find similar solution for Slack API [here](https://github.com/obaarne/Nagios2Slack).